# Entering a cellvalue if one of the cells in a range is changed and deleting it if range is empty

Tags: vba, excel

I want to make a code that adds a certain value to the first column if values are added to a certain range. And delete that value if that range is empty.
This is what I have so far, but I keep getting errors and I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim rng As Range, cell As Range

On Error GoTo haveError

Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B1:G100"))

If Not rng Is Nothing Then
Application.EnableEvents = False
For Each cell In rng.Cells
    If cell.Value = "blah" Then
        Range("A" & cell.Row).Value = "derp"
    End If
    Next
For Each cell In rng.Cells
    If Range("B" & cell.Row, "G" & cell.Row).Value = "" Then
        Range("A" & cell.Row).ClearContents
    End If
    Next
Application.EnableEvents = True

End If
Exit Sub

haveError:
MsgBox Err.Description
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You got `Type mismatch` error for wrong syntax in this line:

```
If Range("B" & cell.Row, "G" & cell.Row).Value = "" Then
```

So, I modified it and it work well. I also reduce one looping because both condition can set in only one looping.

Here, the full code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range

    On Error GoTo haveError

    Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B1:G100"))

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then

        Application.EnableEvents = False

        For Each cell In rng.Cells

            If cell.Value = "blah" Then
                Me.Range("A" & cell.Row).Value = "derp"
            End If

            If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Me.Range("B" & cell.Row & ":" & "G" & cell.Row)) = 0 Then
                Me.Range("A" & cell.Row).ClearContents
            End If

        Next

        Application.EnableEvents = True

    End If

    Exit Sub

haveError:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I've reorganized some commands and only performed actions when they are necessary.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    'don't do anything unless there is something to do
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B1:G100")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo haveError
        'don't declare vars until you kow you will need them
        Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
        Application.EnableEvents = False

        Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B1:G100"))
        For Each cell In rng.Cells
            If cell.Value = "blah" Then
                Range("A" & cell.Row).Value = "derp"
            ElseIf Application.CountBlank(Cells(cell.Row, "B").Resize(1, 6)) = 6 Then
                Cells(cell.Row, "A").ClearContents
            End If
    End If
    GoTo safeExit

haveError:
    If CBool(Err.Number) Then
        'Debug.Print Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
        MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
        Err.Clear
    End If
safeExit:
    Set rng = Nothing
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Rather than having two [For Each...Next Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ebk1751.aspx), I've used an `If ... ElseIf ... End If` since the conditions are mutually exclusive (i.e. if one is true, the other cannot be true).